# HQL - не использовать перебор значений

Tags: hibernate, hql

Есть метод

```
public void updateRole(Set<String> roles, User user) {
    Set<Role> updateUserRoles = new HashSet<>();
    for (String roleName : roles) {
        updateUserRoles.add(roleDao.getRoleByName(roleName));
    }
    user.setRoleSet(updateUserRoles);
}
```

Подскажите как лучше исключить обращение к базе в цикле с помощью использования HQL.

ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ :

Set roles, которая содержит имена вроде ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN ...

На выходе необходимо получить :

Set roles которые были получены из БД.

т.е. что-то вроде :

```
    @Override
    public Set<Role> getRoleSet(Set<String> role) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT roleSet FROM Role r WHERE roleSet.name in (:roleStringSet)")
                .setParameter("roleStringSet", role)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

только возвращался бы Set )

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Set<Role> getRoleSet(Set<String> role) {
    return new HashSet<>(entityManager.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.name in (:roleStringSet)")
            .setParameter("roleStringSet", role)
            .getResultList());
}
```